# How is the reference of mixin pass to another mixin in python?

Tags: python

If a class is inheriting multiple class, why can the superclasses access functions of the other superclasses mutually? Where is the superclass getting the referencing from?

For example

```
class A():
    def a_method(self):
        print "I am a"

class B():
    def b_method(self):
        self.a_method()

class test(A, B):
    def test_method(self):
        self.b_method()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_instance = test()
    # Will print a_method
    test_instance.test_method()

    test_b = B()

    try:
        # will raise exception
        test_b.b_method()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Comment: The superclass isn't doing it, the subclass is.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a class as inheriting from two superclasses

```
class test(A, B):
```

it inherits the methods from both superclasses into the **same** namespace. So, from `test()`, you can call both `self.a_method()` and `self.b_method()`. Your question, I assume, is why calling `self.b_method()` works from an instance of `test`, but not an instance of `B`. It works in `test` because both methods are in the same namespace, and when `b_method()` calls `a_method()`, it can be "seen" from inside the class, and the call succeeds. When instantiating `B`, which does not inherit from `A`, `a_method()` is not visible, and so an exception is raised.

The methods and attributes associated with a class or instance can be examined with [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

```
>>> test_instance = test()
>>> dir(test_instance)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'a_method', 'b_method', 'test_method']
```